# Do average native-speakers have difficulties in correctly pronouncing science-related words?

Tags: pronunciation

Do average native-speakers have difficulties in correctly pronouncing science-related words ( e.g. 'coelenterate' or 'chelicerae')?

Comment: Yes, I expect someone who had not studied biology would be uncertain how to pronounce those words.

Comment: When it comes to words and expressions borrowed from other (esp. classical) languages, being native can't be of much help. Everyone needs to learn them the same hard way.

Comment: Just look what they've done to *psychology*.

Comment: This question is way too general.  Could you provide some examples?

Answer (score 1):

I think even science-related headlines are harder to pronounce when reading. It depends on if the community is interested in general science or working on science-related jobs (engineering, medical science, social sciences) or if it's a daily habit of someone wondering about nature, society or history.

Answer (score 0):

Native english speakers may have difficulties in correctly pronouncing latinate words unless they have a perfect understanding of latin.

Comment: There isn't a single agreed-upon pronunciation of Latin, so while an educated person might understand the etymological roots, that does not mean that all educated people will pronounce those roots in the same way.